# Reading Image from AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax, image, image-processing

I have a url that when requested will return an image. I want the url to be requested through an AJAX request. The ajax request returns binary data which is what is being deplayed. but i want the actual image displayed not the binary data. Am using php on the server side and i have set the below headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Content-type: text/jpg; charset=windows-1251");
```

Please i need advise on what i need to do.

Comment: (1) Stop wanting that. That way leads to insanity. Just get a URL for the image and set it as the src of an <img> (2) The content type for a JPEG is image/jpeg not text/jpg (and it doesn't have a character set ... or characters)

Comment: thanks for the response, how can i get to know if the image is fully loaded, as i would only like to display it when it is fully loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send an url to this Photo, even if its just a PHP file with an ID

For example

```
<img src='thumbGenerator.php?id=1337' />
```

And then this PHP file outputs the binary data.

Comment: To be more specific, just use javascript to re-set the src attribute for the image rather than making an AJAX call to your script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on [`data` urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs) for binary image data.  Keep in mind this method isn't supported in Internet Explorer.  If you need cross-browser compatibility then you will need to store the files somewhere on the server and link to them using the images `src` attribute.  Or link the `src` attribute to a php script that generates the images and serves them correctly.